# In WordPress, how can I push a button and redirect all my current visitors to another page?

Tags: javascript, php, wordpress, redirect, buddypress

I'm hosting a virtual event in BuddyPress and I want admins to be able to redirect all users who are viewing any number of specified pages, to a single page.  It's an WordPress/browser version of the behavior that Zoom has for breakout rooms.  Where the "host" can move attendees between locations on the platform.

I want to be able to do the same with WordPress visitors.

I've gotten close with a WP Plugin that is a "countdown timer" and the action when the timer hits zero is to redirect to another page.  I want to do the same thing, on with "the push of a button" rather than at a specified time.

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you can simply do this with HTML using the anchor tag. Like this

```
<a href="/new-page">Redirect</a>
```

"redirect" is the text that will be visible to the user
the /new-page will be the URL of the page you want to redirect.

Comment: Correct me if I'm wrong, but this ^^above^^ would be a link (on a page) that each user could click to go to /new-page.  I'm looking for a way that I (as a group leader) can "pull" everyone.  I call it "yoinking".  I pull them.  I don't want to wait for (or depend on) them to decide when to return.